# Why is only one date under DST influence?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, pytz

I've been reading the pytz and datetime module documentation but I can't figure out why one date is under DST and the other is not.

```
import pytz
import datetime

mytz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')

od = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 4, 0)

mytz.localize(od)
# Out: datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 4, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)

mytz.localize(od).dst()
# Out: datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)

dt = datetime.datetime(2089, 7, 1, 4, 0)

mytz.localize(dt)
# Out: datetime.datetime(2089, 7, 1, 4, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)

mytz.localize(dt).dst()
# Out: datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Comment: Nobody alive today knows whether dates in 2089 will be DST or not. So, there’s not even a *correct* answer here. It would make sense for pytz to carry on today’s rule, unless it’s known that it’s about to be abolished. But it also makes just as much sense for the answer to be what it is. Why exactly the DST rule seems to “expire”… someone would have to actually dig a bit deeper.

Comment: @deceze OK but what about 2088, is what you say true then, what about 2087, what about .. down to 2022, why is that any more definite? What year does pytz give up (according to you) assuming DST rules are unknown? Anyway there’s this little issue on the pytz github; dates after 2038 currently give wrong DST https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/31

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of the time zone rules, you find that they can have a keyword "max" specified that "*is used to extend a rule’s application into the indefinite future*" [ref](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-how-to.html). For the US, you can find that [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/5c79ca1f7b574798dc5f05ab0eeaae30ceb948e4/northamerica#L185). Unless otherwise specified, DST just continues to be applied during the specified period of the year. But keep in mind that this does not mean that it will actually be the case in the future, since time zones are subject to political decisions.

As an addition to @balmy 's comment suggesting this is a deficiency of `pytz`, Python 3.9's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) gives the result to be expected from the above:

```
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

od = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 4, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))
print(od.dst())
# 1:00:00

dt = datetime.datetime(2089, 7, 1, 4, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))
print(dt.dst())
# 1:00:00
```